# Gettings errors: Texture is not cubemap complete, and INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D in IE 11

Tags: three.js, textures, webgl, texture-mapping

I have seen various examples of cubemaps made with images served from the local file system, but I haven't been able to find any examples where the images are being dynamically loaded from an external website and populating the cubemap. I have figured a way to do this, and it works perfectly fine in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Edge and IOS browsers as well. But, not surprisingly, it doesn't work in IE 11.
When trying to open up the cube map, the console spits out the following errors:

**WEBGL11003: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D**

**WEBGL11122: drawArrays: Texture is not cubemap complete. All cubemaps faces must be defined and be the same size**

The textures are the same size and have defined width and height.

```
var controls, scene, camera, renderer;
var cameraCube, sceneCube;
var textureEquirec, textureCube, loader, cubeMaterial, cubeShader;
var cubeMesh;
var geometry, material, mesh;
var pause;

function init(seat) {

    // SCENE
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    sceneCube = new THREE.Scene();

    // CAMERAS
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.set(0,0,-1000);
    cameraCube = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100000);

    // LIGHTS
    var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
    scene.add(ambient);

    // TEXTURES
    cubeShader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "cube" ];
    cubeMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
        fragmentShader: cubeShader.fragmentShader,
        vertexShader: cubeShader.vertexShader,
        uniforms: cubeShader.uniforms,
        depthWrite: false,
        side: THREE.BackSide
    });

    updateTexture(seat);
    textureCube.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
    textureCube.mapping = THREE.CubeReflectionMapping;
    textureCube.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

    cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 100, 100), cubeMaterial);
    sceneCube.add(cubeMesh);

    geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(400.0, 24, 24);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.autoClear = false;
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setFaceCulling(THREE.CullFaceNone);

    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
    modal.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    cameraCube.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    cameraCube.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
    if (pause) return;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
    controls.update();
}

function render() {
    var timer = -0.0002 * Date.now();
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    cameraCube.rotation.copy(camera.rotation);
    renderer.render(sceneCube, cameraCube);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function loadTexture(texture){
    scope.loadingView = true;
    if (textureCube) {
        textureCube.dispose();
    }
    loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
    loader.setCrossOrigin('anonymous');
    textureCube = loader.load(texture, onLoadCallback, null, onErrorCallback);
    cubeMaterial.uniforms.tCube.value = textureCube;
}

function updateTexture(seat){
    var path = CDNDomain + '/cloud/assets/';
    var files = [
        path + 'pathtoimage.jpg',
        path + 'pathtoimage.jpg',
        path + 'pathtoimage.jpg',
        path + 'pathtoimage.jpg',
        path + 'pathtoimage.jpg',
        path + 'pathtoimage.jpg',
    ];
    loadTexture(files);
}

function initializeControls(){
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
    controls.minDistance = 500;
    controls.maxDistance = 2500;
}

function onLoadCallback(loaded) {
    scope.$apply(function(){
       scope.loadingView = false;
    });
    initializeControls();
    animate();
}

function onErrorCallback(error){
    scope.loadingMsg = 'There was an error processing your request.';
}
```

I'm calling the init function on the press of a button and passing data.

Answer (score 0):

Realized that the textures aren't the power of 2. After changing the size of the images the issue is fixed in IE11.